# How convert input type="date" in a timestamp?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date, timestamp

I need to convert an `<input type="date">` value in a timestamp. This is my HTML code:

```
 <input type="date" name="date_end" id="date_end">
```

This field has a value that I have put like `25/10/2017`

My jQuery code is:

```
var dataEnd = $('[name="date_end"]').val();
        if (!dataEnd) {
            return false;
        } else {
            var timestamp_end=$('[name="date_start"]').val().getTime();
            console.log("TIMESTAMP END "+timestamp_end);
.....
}
```

But this is not working... why not?

Comment: Maybe `new Date(parseInt($('[name="date_start"]').val(), 10))` will help somehow?

Comment: can you add the HTML code

Comment: @sunpietro—the value of an input type date is an ISO 8601 format date string like "2017-10-24". Giving that to *parseInt* will return the number 2017. If that value is passed to the Date constructor, it will be treated as milliseconds since the epoch and result in a Date for 1970-01-01T00:00:02.017Z. So no, it won't help somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make a new `Date()` passing the value of your input as parameter, then call `getTime()`. here an example:

```js
$('[name="date_end"]').on('change',function() {
  var dataEnd = $(this).val();
  console.log((new Date(dataEnd)).getTime());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="date_end" id="date_end">
```

Comment: You should be careful with that. The value returned from an input type date is an ISO 8601 format date string. If parsed by a built-in parser that is consistent with recent versions of ECMA-262, it will be interpreted as UTC. So where a user's time zone is, say, UTC-0800 and at 10pm selects a date of 2017-10-26, the UTC date will be 2017-10-27, which might come as a surprise.

Answer (score 3):

do this

```
var dateEnd = $('#date_end').val()
var var timestamp_end = Date.parse(date_end)
```

or 
in a single line

```
var timestamp_end = Date.parse($('#date_end').val())
```

it works and it's clean

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Solution ( Using pure js ) , I used the unary plus operator operator after converting the value into javascript date object.

```js
function checkDateValue(){
  var dateConvertedToTimestamp = (+new Date(document.getElementById('date_value').value));
  
  document.getElementById('date_value_timestamp').innerHTML  = dateConvertedToTimestamp ;
}
```

```html
<input type='date' id='date_value'>
<button onClick='checkDateValue()'> Submit </button>

<div>Timestamp:- <span id='date_value_timestamp'></span></div>
```

Comment: The value returned by a date input is an ISO 8601 formatted date string like 2017-10-26, which will be parsed as UTC (mostly), when the user might be expecting it to be parsed as local.

Comment: @RobG to get local timezone specific timestamp you can use getTimezoneOffset prototype method of Date object.

Comment: You've completely missed the point: the user likely expects the value to be treated as local, but your function will treat it as UTC. So it will represent a different moment in time (and hence have a different timestamp, regardless of the format) to that expected by the user.

Comment: @RobG in that case would you please suggest something which will result in User expected value.

Answer (score 0):

I needed an UNIX timestamp and updated Partha Roy's anwser for my needs.

Javascript :

```
  document.getElementById('dateInput').addEventListener('change', function (){
        
  let inputDate = document.getElementById('dateInput').value ;
  let dateConvertedToTimestamp = new Date(inputDate).getTime() ;
  console.log(dateConvertedToTimestamp) ;
  document.getElementById('resultTime').value = dateConvertedToTimestamp / 1000 ;
    }) ;
```

The /1000 division convert to UNIX timestamp + I track all input change and not only when the form is submited.

HTML :

```
<input type='date' id='dateInput'>
<input type='hidden' id='resultTime' name='dateTimestamp'>
```

Don't forget date input are still not well supported, so we can easily adapt this code with classic numbers input.

Comment: this will not yield a local timestamp but a GMT timestamp

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d = new Date(parseInt($('[name="date_start"]').val()));
var n = d.getTime();
console.log(n);
</script>
```

Comment: The value returned by a date input is an ISO 8601 formatted date string like 2017-10-26. Giving that to *parseInt* will result in the number 2017 which, when passed to the date constructor, results in a date for 1970-01-01T00:00:02.017Z.