# How to show Date in Input type date from Ajax response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, date, datetime, model-view-controller

My control is,

```
<input type="date" id="DecDate" name="birthday">
```

I save it in db and can view it in this form ,

```
3/10/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

when i try to update same record i populate it in "DecDate" from response coming from Ajax in json format.

i tried this,

```
$('#DecDate').val(response.DecisionDate);
```

its not showing me any date.

I alert response it shows me same above date as "`/Date(1583787600000)/`"

I dont know why it is showing differently on alert and how should i populate it in control.

EDIT:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "@Url.Action("JqueryFillControl")",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { id: Id },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response != null) {

                            const d = new Date(response.DecisionDate);
                            const formattedDate = d.getFullYear() + '-' + ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2)
                            $('#DecDate').val(formattedDate);
                        } else {
                            alert("Something went wrong");
                        }
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is same time but showing in Epoch.
You can verify it using below,
https://www.epochconverter.com/

Use new Date(value) to convert it into Date object.

Follow this if needed.

[How convert input type="date" in timestamp javascript-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929778/how-convert-input-type-date-in-timestamp-javascript-jquery)

Comment: i the following link they are changing it to some date format. i niteed to populate my date control with response value

Answer (score 0):

The date format used by HTML5 date control is like `yyyy-mm-dd`. So, that might be one of the issues here. So, you can convert the `DecisionDate` to Date object and get the proper date format to display in control like:

```
const d = new Date(response.DecisionDate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
const formattedDate = d.getFullYear()+'-'+("0"+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+("0"+d.getDate()).slice(-2)
$('#DecDate').val( formattedDate );
```

**DEMO:**

```js
const decisionDate = '/Date(1583787600000)/';
const d = new Date(decisionDate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
const formattedDate = d.getFullYear()+'-'+("0"+(d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+'-'+("0"+d.getDate()).slice(-2)
$('#DecDate').val( formattedDate );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="DecDate" name="birthday">
```

Comment: @palash thanks for your response but i am getting this exception while using above code "The specified value "NaN-aN-aN" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"."

Comment: Can you please share what does `console.log( response.DecisionDate )` & `console.log( typeof response.DecisionDate )` are showing in the console?

Comment: @palash consol.log showing /Date(1583787600000)/  value

Comment: It seems your date is in json format. Please try the update code in the first part.

Answer (score 0):

So regarding your scenario, you can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) which is a very good library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and displaying dates and times in `JavaScript`. Please refer to the below example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="date"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//var DecisionDate='3/10/2020 12:00:00 AM';
var DecisionDate='March 11 2020 12:00:00 AM';
var d=moment(DecisionDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss a');
$("#date").text(d);     
alert(d);
</script>
```

Note: You would need to refer to the `moment.js` file either by installing it locally or using the CDN link provided in the demo.

Working DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/01e7fwv8/